# Laravel cache void value

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-5.7

Is that a good practise to store a void value as that?

```
Cache::remember($cacheName, $this->time, function() use ($data) {
    $this->someTransformation($data, ['title', 'url']);
    return 1;
});
```

The point is: when I do not return anything from remember method - nothing is cached and I have to call `someTransformation` which includes some API calls again. This seems like it's working but I am not sure about whether there is not anything better.

Comment: This looks like a code smell. You're using the `Cache::remember` for the consequences of the function and not to actually cache anything. The idea is you cache the result of an expensive computation so you can retrieve it later from the cache without re-doing the computation.

Comment: If you don't want to store anything, I don't think Cache is the thing you need.

Comment: Oh I see. I will change it that way. Thank you